# Accessing uibutton action from a different class Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, class, custom-cell

I have an `UITableView` that is loaded from two custom cell `xib` files.
The second one contains an `UIButton`.

But since i've added the custom class for `xib` - it has its own actions and functions, which i cannot access from `ViewController`.

My goal is to apply some action on `UIButton` when the custom cell is loaded in the tableview.

My function is defined in ViewController (because all variables are there) and my `UIButton` action is defined in Custom class for `xib`.

How do i connect one to another?

Thank you

Comment: that would be a nice option, but you have to assign a separate class file for a custom-cell xib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by simply posting a notification.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("buttonClickedNotification", object: nil)
```

Post this notification from your button method in custom class. You can also pass any data by using object parameter (Here it is nil).

And observe the notification in your viewController.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "buttonClicked:", name: "buttonClickedNotification", object: nil)
```

And implement buttonClicked() method in your viewController.

```
func buttonClicked(data: NSNotification)
{
   //If any data is passed get it using
   let receivedData:NSDictionary = data.object as! NSDictionary   //If data is of NSDictionary type.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Here is the solution in swift**

If you want to perform action in another class when an event takes place in another class, then you have to use [Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) in your code, so that you can perform the action in another class.

For example

Declare your protocol like this before the class interface

```
protocol MyDelegateClass {
    func btnAction()
}
```

Define your protocol in the interface of your class like this

```
var MyDelegateClass! = nil
```

Now on your button action trigger the protocol like this

```
 @IBAction func btnProtocolAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    [delegate btnAction];
}
```

Now include the protocol in the class like this

```
class myActionClass: UIViewController, PopUpViewDelegate {
```

Now assign the protocol to the MyDelegateClass object like this

```
myProtocolObject.delegate=self
```

Also define the class which you have declared in MyDelegateClass like

```
func btnAction() {
  print(@"This method will triggered");
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Write a delegate method.  This will connect your ViewController and Custom Class.  What have you tried already?

Comment: Please add more detail to your solution.